# Concurrency call to SQL - Get Unique Number

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, postgresql, entity-framework-core

What I am trying to achieve:
In an Web App (Blazor Server), we generate some documents.
Each document, should have a unique sequence number.

The Sequence Number must be between X and Y, where Y always > X.
The Sequence Number (X and Y) is set at the beginning of each year by a Superadmin.

The values are saved in a SQL Server or PSQL database, via EF Core 6.

Normal Flow:

- First document is generated : gets the ID 1.
- Second document is generated from the app : gets the ID 2.
- Last document is generated from the app : gets the ID Y.
- Last document + 1 > gets an error.

Now, my only problem is: how can I treat concurrent calls?
What happens if in the same millisecond two users try to get the same Id?
Can SQL guarantee to me that each one will have the next Sequence Number?

Comment: [SEQUENCE NUMBERS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sequence-numbers/sequence-numbers?msclkid=aafe7f74aa8611eca5e9fec771626b79&view=sql-server-ver15)?

Comment: Must be managed by admin, not by SQL (the start and end of the sequence number)

Comment: Sequences could be programmatically created. You need just an interface to let the admin input the parameters required.

Comment: The only way that is scalable **and** safe for concurrent use is to use a [sequence](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createsequence.html)

Comment: There are ways to do it, but why reinvent the wheel? Identity or sequence already does this. Are you really using both RDBMS? Because each has different ways to go about this. So if you can choose one people can offer more specific solutions.